# cannot find service class on video view

Tags: android, orientation, media, android-videoview

Hi i want to know how to run a service in background of an activity
like i am using a video view and i want it to run while other activity are running

how to do this?
VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

```
            //Creating MediaController  
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);  
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);          

          //specify the location of media file  
       Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/video.mp4");

          //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView  
       videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);  
       videoView.setVideoURI(uri);          
       videoView.requestFocus();  
       videoView.start();
```

can any one help me how to bind service with this video view so it run in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
VideoView videoView =(VideoView)context.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
```

Comment: this will be declare in MyService class or in activity.java class?

Comment: In your service class. If you are going to Service class from an Activity, then you can pass your context(YourActivity.this) from activity to service and use the same in service class as context instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: i am sending both service class and activity class to you can you help me to add it

Comment: First tell me how i can send source code to you because when i posthere it shows exceed charcter limit?

Comment: But why do you want to do that? It's just simple. Pass context as extra via intent. and use it

Comment: Context in your case is nothing but "YourActivityName.this"

Comment: i add this line public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
      startService(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

Comment: and in my activity i add this linestartService(new Intent(this, MyService.class)); inside oncreate method but when i play video in my phone and press home button video again stop playing what to do i have only two class MainActivity.java and also MyService.java i also declare in Android Manifest.xml file service as<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" /> but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to [bind the `Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingBoundService) to your `Activity` if you need to interact with it. You can pass your `VideoView` throw your `IBinder` implementation if you need to handle it through the service. You should also [run the `Service` in the foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) if you want to avoid it getting killed.